# iOS class that allows an image to "drift" across screen?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, nstimer

I've seen a lot of helpful tutorials that show one how to:

1. make an image move according to a predefined path, or
2. move the image, a few pixels at a time,  in response to a UIButton.

What I want to do is have the image "drift" arbitrarily according to an Vxy velocity I define, then have the button(s) change the velocity. (Yes, I'd have it slow down with time if no action made).

In other languages there might have been a way to do Change Pxy position by Vxy (to ad infinitum) unless button pushed. I believe GET was the command.  I can think of a way to do that in iOS I suppose but that would involve setting up a series of 1 sec CGMutablePathRef anims.   Alternatively, I have seen some talk of NSTimer: would it be a good practice to introduce some sort of delay:  draw, delay, draw, delay.

**Request:** specific classes or terms I can search in the manuals for myself.

Comment: I don't believe there's any single class that would enable you to do this, but the Core Animation suite would definitely be one part of a solution, along with possibly Core Graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iirc using uiview's animateWithDuration:completion is cheaper than using core animation. frame is an animatable property. So, yeah I think I would use an NSTimer to call your method for default calculation of the end frame of your view and then call animateWithDuration:completion there.

Comment: You are incorrect in that `UIView` animations are cheaper than using CA. They are one and the same under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for that. Can't remember where I thought I read that.

Comment: I don't think UIView animations are powerful enough to allow for the kind of animations that the OP is talking about. For example, he wants to slow down the animation when there's no activity and the only way to control this would be `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut` which he has no control over, while using a CAKeyframe animation would give the OP complete control over the timing.

Comment: I want full control.  Here is how I would do it in povray;

    // for any value of frame_number 
    #declare n=0;
    #while (n<frame_number)
        #declare V=<0.1,0.2,0.1>;
        #declare P=<0,0,0>;
        #declare P=P+V;
        #declare V=V*0.9;
    #declare n=n+1;
    #end
    
    sphere{P,0.1 pigment{green}}

     THEN UIButton somehow can occasionally intervene and make:
    #declare V=V+something;

Comment: I am now stumbling through the code at Apple's SimpleGestureRecognizers, which is answering more questions.

Comment: At this point, seems like my answer should not be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

[deleted bad idea]

I ran across a wonderful tutorial for anyone considering such a project;
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH_Rj152DRM

I believe the key "noob" problem I was having was in not realizing I should declare the instance variable for my sprite/ image in the

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
```

then work on other properties of the animation in touches/ other user events. Once I figured that out, I am now capable of doing the heavy lifting for the rest of the project myself.